# Почему данный код приводит к зависанию приложения?

Tags: c#, wpf

Здравствуйте.

Почему данный код приводит к зависанию? После вывода MessageBox на экран в приложении приложение зависает и MessageBox невозможно закрыть. Как сделать, чтобы не было зависания?

```
using MouseKeyboardActivityMonitor;
using MouseKeyboardActivityMonitor.WinApi;

public partial class MainWindow:Window {

    public MainWindow() 
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Activate();
    }

    // First, a MouseHookListener object must exist in the class private KeyboardHookListener m_mouseListener;
    // Subroutine for activating the hook
    public void Activate() 
    {

        // Note: for an application hook, use the AppHooker class instead
        m_mouseListener = new KeyboardHookListener(new GlobalHooker());

        // The listener is not enabled by default
        m_mouseListener.Enabled = true;

        // Set the event handler
        // recommended to use the Extended handlers, which allow input suppression among other additional information
        m_mouseListener.KeyDown += new System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventHandler(m_mouseListener_KeyDown);

    }

    public void Deactivate() 
    {
        try 
        {
            m_mouseListener.Dispose();
        }
        catch 
        {
            m_mouseListener.Enabled = false;
        }
    }

    private void m_mouseListener_KeyDown(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs e) 
    {
        if (e.KeyData == Keys.Left) 
        {
            System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("1");

            m_mouseListener.Enabled = false;

            Deactivate();

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

MessageBox - это по сути слип в программе. Когда вы выводите сообщение, приложение останавливается для того, чтобы пользователь принял решение. Это обеспечивает динамическую логику программы. Либо засуньте мессэджбокс в другой поток, либо переместите его в наиболее подходящее место...